# Sprite kit: How to make physics body of a sprite to copy an actual image?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I know how to make that in gamescene.sks – you just need to select a sprite and check "alpha mask" in body type form.
But how to do it programmatically? I'm afraid that my manipulations with .sks will end up bad. So i want to do it via swift code. I looked physics body related methods and properties and haven't found anything near to that "alpha mask"

Answer (score 0):

You didn't find anything alpha related? Might want to look closer... The docs for [`bodyWithTexture:size:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html%23//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithTexture:size:) say (emphasis added):

> Use this method when your sprite has a shape that you want replicated in its physics body... A new physics body is created that **includes all of the texels in the texture that have a nonzero alpha value**.

See also [`bodyWithTexture:alphaThreshold:size:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html%23//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithTexture:alphaThreshold:size:) if you want to change the alpha threshold.

Comment: Thanks, @rickster! I was too neglectful, that's what I needed